# I need to append data to an existing table in Access from 2 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have data in two tables:

`tbl_games` has the following columns:

```
game_id, season, date, home_team, visiting_team, 
home_score, visiting score, home_score_half_time, visiting score_half_time
```

`tbl_formation` has the following columns:

```
game_id, home_formation, home_team, visiting_team, visiting_formation
```

I would like to append data from these tables into a `game_team` table that has the following columns:

```
game_id, team_id, status, end_score, half_score, Formation
```

Instead of separating out `home_team` `visiting_team` I would like to have them all under `team_id` and status indicating whether it was a home team or a visiting team for a certain game.

I was experimenting with the query below but it did not work

```
INSERT INTO Game_Team ( game_id, Team_ID, End_Score, half_score, Formation )
SELECT G.game_id, G.home_team, G.home_score_half_time, G.home_score, GL.home_formation
FROM tbl_games AS G 
INNER JOIN tbl_formation AS GL ON G.game_id = GL.game_id;
```

Comment: if you are wanting to see the data then why are you using INSERT INTO?

Comment: How it didn't work? Any errors? Post them please. Not the desired results?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Game_Team ( game_id, Team_ID, End_Score, half_score, Formation )
values(SELECT G.game_id, G.home_team, G.home_score_half_time, G.home_score, GL.home_formation
FROM tbl_games AS G 
INNER JOIN tbl_formation AS GL ON G.game_id = GL.game_id);
```

I have added values.
See [insert data from one table to another in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907863/insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
INSERT INTO Game_Team ( game_id, Team_ID, End_Score, half_score, Formation )
SELECT G.game_id, G.home_team & ' ' & G.visiting_team, G.home_score_half_time, G.home_score, GL.home_formation
FROM tbl_games AS G 
INNER JOIN tbl_formation AS GL ON G.game_id = GL.game_id;
```