# Combining two columns and adding it to another table in Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following fields in tbl_games

game_id, home_team, visiting_team

I would like to move the data in these columns to another table called game_team where

game_id=game_id and home_team and visiting_team would be combined under team_id and another column called status would indicate whether the team is a "home" or "visiting"

how can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need to append data to an existing table in Access from 2 tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619984/i-need-to-append-data-to-an-existing-table-in-access-from-2-tables)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

```
INSERT INTO game_team (game_id, team_id, status)
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT game_id, home_team, 'home' FROM tbl_games 
  UNION ALL
 SELECT game_id, visiting_team, 'visiting' FROM tbl_games) q
```

Comment: It still did not work. Where I would like to get to is... Original: game_id 1 home_team A visiting team B  to game_id 1 team_id A status home game_id 1 team_id B status visiting  I cannot break it out in this editor

Comment: Well, then please consider to post in your original question exact `CREATE TABLE` statements for both table, sample data in tabular form.