# How should i write query in MySQL for getting values from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want some field datas to get inserted from a table(called profile) to another table(services) along with those field datas in the table(to which the values want to be inserted,i.e. services).But I am failing. I am new to MySQL and database queries i need ur help.

```
  $qur = mysql_query("INSERT INTO services(FirstName,LastName,DOB,Mobile,email,CountryCode,Address,State,City,Country,PinCode,altmobnumber,PanCard,AdharCard,ServiceOffering,Fee,FeeDuration,FeeExtraHour,negotiable) select profile.FirstName,profile.LastName,profile.DOB,profile.Mobile,profile.email,profile.CountryCode,profile.Address,profile.State,profile.City,profile.Country,profile.PinCode from profile where id = '$id'")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [insert data from one table to another in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907863/insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-in-mysql)

Comment: Your code looks working. Just checkout fields names and order.

Comment: @Ostrovski The code does _not_ look like it is working.  He is trying to `INSERT` the wrong number of columns in his `SELECT` statement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen and because of that I wrote about checking fields.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify value for every column in your `VALUES` list. If you do not have any value from the `SELECT` statement, either use a `NULL` value for respective field or simply remove it from the `VALUES` list.

e.g. if you want to insert three values in tbl1 but tbl2 contains only 2 fields, use a `NULL` value for the third field

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (a, b, c) SELECT tbl2.a, tbl2.b, NULL FROM tbl2
```

or if you have a hard coded value,

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (a, b, c) SELECT tbl2.a, tbl2.b, some_value FROM tbl2
```

or simply use only two fields

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (a, b) SELECT tbl2.a, tbl2.b FROM tbl2
```

Now, the `VALUES` part of your query has 19 fields but your `SELECT` statement provides only 11 fields. Either add `NULL` for the last 8 fields for successful execution or remove the last 8 fields from `VALUES` list

Comment: Syntax error... Remove VALUES. (And you can also skip to list columns that need NULL, and also skip selecting NULL for those.)

Comment: Alternatively, you can do INSERT INTO tbl1 (a, b) SELECT tbl2.a, tbl2.b FROM tbl2, which will insert NULL or default value (if specified) into column c.

Comment: ok it might be solving, suppose if i want to insert other values into the table  after the where clause in the above query, how to write that query? suppose query looks like INSERT INTO tbl1 (a, b,c,d,e,f) SELECT tbl2.a, tbl2.b FROM tbl2 where id='$id',c,d,e,f ;

Comment: if you cant remove fields from `VALUES` list and want to insert a hardcoded value instead of `NULL`, make it a part of the `SELECT` statement. Correct query for the case you've mentioned would be `INSERT INTO tbl1 (a, b,c,d,e,f) SELECT tbl2.a, tbl2.b, c, d, e, f FROM tbl2 where id='$id'`

Comment: c,d,e,f From tbl2  ? c,d,e,f will be the values of tbl1 .

Comment: actually it should be `INSERT INTO tbl1 (a, b,c,d,e,f) SELECT tbl2.a, tbl2.b, '$var_c', $var_d, $var_e, $var_f FROM tbl2 where id='$id'` i.e. this will insert the value of $var_c, $var_d, $var_e, $var_f in fields c, d, e, f of tbl1. $var_c is string or date hence wrapped in single quotes where as the rest are numbers. These values/variables do not come from tbl2 but from your PHP code

Comment: but i want the id  where clause checking, the id of tble2

Comment: '$var_c', $var_d, $var_e, $var_f values  are getting into tbl1 but its nt bringing values of a,b from tbl2