# Select data from db table 1 and insert it into another db table 2 in php

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I have two different Databases, names:

1. dbtest: Table 1
2. dbtest2: Table 2

I want to select all the data and new entries from dbtest Table 1  to dbtest2 Table 2.

I have tried this

```
$sqlfin = "INSERT INTO dbtest2.Table2 SELECT * FROM dbtest.Table1";
$resultfi = mysqli_query($db_conn, $sqlfin);
```

But no luck so far. How can I assure that new Records are insert into both table ? Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from)

Comment: seems your query is fine, what error you get on above query

Comment: The query is correct . Try running the query in db directly.If insert happens properly then something wrong with php code . Also check if transactions are committed in db if not you can’t see the data .

Comment: @kartik could you be more clearify on transactions are committed .?

Comment: @Ashley Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411332/select-data-from-db-table-1-and-insert-it-into-another-db-table-2-in-php/47411571#47411571

Comment: @Ashley  what I meant is , after any DML statements we need to commit . We need to run “commit” command .

Comment: Thanks all of you ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

lets try it in this format

```
INSERT INTO `dbtest2`.`Table2` SELECT * FROM `dbtest`.`Table1`
```

> The following conditions hold for INSERT ... SELECT statements:
>
> - Specify IGNORE to ignore rows that would cause duplicate-key    violations.
> - AUTO_INCREMENT columns work as usual.
> - To ensure that the binary log can be used to re-create the original tables, MySQL does not permit concurrent inserts for INSERT ... SELECT
>     statements (see [Section 8.11.3, “Concurrent Inserts”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/concurrent-inserts.html)).
> - To avoid ambiguous column reference problems when the SELECT and the    INSERT refer to the same table, provide a unique alias for each
>     table    used in the SELECT part, and qualify column names in that
>     part with    the appropriate alias.

[INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

---

**Create Trigger:** for adding new entries

```
CREATE TRIGGER copy_record BEFORE INSERT ON dbtest.Table1 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO dbtest2.Table2 (first_name, last_name) VALUES (new.first_name, new.last_name); 
END
```

> trigger_event indicates the kind of operation that activates the
>   trigger. These trigger_event values are permitted:
>
> ```
> INSERT: The trigger activates whenever a new row is inserted into the table; for example, through INSERT, LOAD DATA, and REPLACE
> ```
>
> statements.
>
> ```
> UPDATE: The trigger activates whenever a row is modified; for example, through UPDATE statements.
>
> DELETE: The trigger activates whenever a row is deleted from the table; for example, through DELETE and REPLACE statements. DROP TABLE
> ```
>
> and TRUNCATE TABLE statements on the table do not activate this
>   trigger, because they do not use DELETE. Dropping a partition does not
>   activate DELETE triggers, either.

[CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html)

Comment: Okay @AZinkey it does makes sense.. now the problem is its not updating the new entries . Thanks

Comment: new entries means the user input.. Like what ever the user posts it will go first to db.Table1 and then goes to db.Table2 ..

Comment: idk why its not working, 
Can you see this 

$sqlfin= "CREATE TRIGGER copy_records AFTER INSERT ON `dbtest`.`Table1` FOR EACH ROW FOLLOWS BEGIN INSERT INTO `dbtest2`.`Table2` END";

I also change the trigger_order to PRECEDES ..

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER copy_record BEFORE INSERT ON `dbtest`.`Table1` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO `dbtest2`.`Table2` (first_name, last_name) VALUES (new.first_name, new.last_name); END

Comment: Zinkey Okay now its working.. Thanks for following me all the way up to here .. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this query for your desired task :

**Query First** *(Create Table exactly same like in old database, if you have not)*:

```
CREATE TABLE dbtest2.Table2 LIKE dbtest.Table1;
```

**Query Second** *(Insert all data to newly created table)*  :

```
INSERT INTO dbtest2.Table2 SELECT * FROM dbtest.Table1;
```

Comment: hope this help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks correct but will fail if the 2 tables have a different structure. Specify the columns to avoid it like:

```
INSERT INTO dbtest2.Table2 (2_col_1, 2_col_2) SELECT 1_col_1, 1_col_2 FROM dbtest.Table1
```

---

With PDO (kind of alternative answer, I don't know much for *Mysqli*):
You could connect to **Mysql** with **PDO** without giving a database name when working with multiple ones *(but this isn't mandatory)*, like:

```
$db = new PDO( "mysql:host=" . $host . ";", $user, $password, $options );
```

Then write the Database names, tables and columns like when making a `JOIN` (as you did): separated by a `.`

```
// an example ..
$useDb = $db->query("INSERT INTO db_1.table1 (value_1, value_2) SELECT value_3, value_4 FROM db_2.table2 WHERE db_2.table2.id = 5");
```

*(example tested and working fine)*

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO dbtest2 ( 
      id, 
      name, 
      status ) 
SELECT id, 
      name,          
       '1'
FROM dbtest
ORDER BY id ASC
```

You can use INSERT...SELECT syntax. Note that you can quote '1' directly in the SELECT part.

Comment: Please check that link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907863/insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-in-mysql

Comment: @Nims this working but its only working when there are two tables in the same db..

Comment: btw Thanks Nims, Alex and Tom

Comment: @Ashley Please check that link https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/php-script-to-copy-mysql-tables-from-one-server-to-another-by-database.58303/